# What is the maximum number of cassette teeth compatible with Shimano 11 speed 53-39T, 52-36T & 50-34T crankset?

Tags: compatibility

I want to upgrade my bike which can speedup in flats but also climb efficiently in slopes. Can someone give the maximum number of teeth that would be compatible with those 3 cranksets, if I where to use a MTB RD? Also, I prefer Shimano as they are abundant here in our area and way cheaper than SRAM.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but you might be interested: Shimano 11 speed road and 11 speed MTB is not compatible. If you want to use road shifters and a MTB RD, you'll have to go down to (non-Tiagra 4700) 10 speed road and 9 speed MTB (or use a device that translates the pull ratio, like a Wolftooth Tanpan).

Answer (score 2):

The rear derailleur mostly determines maximum cassette sprocket size. The absolute size of the chainrings does not affect it, but the difference in size between them can limit it.

The largest cassette sprocket size is determined by two rear derailleur specification: the  max sprocket size of course, and the *total capacity*.

Total capacity = difference in min/max sprocket teeth +  difference in min/max chainring teeth. It's basically a measure of how much chain slack a derailleur can take up.

However, for standard modern compact and subcompact cranks the chainring size difference is always 16 (52-36, 50-34, 48-32 etc), so normally the rear derailleur max sprocket size specification practically limits what cassette you can use.

If you combine an MTB rear derailleur and a road crank, the total capacity *might* limit the max cassette sprocket size to less than the derailleur's max sprocket spec, because MTB double cranks typically have a size difference of 10 teeth rather than 16 (at least Shimano's recent offerings do).

If you use a derailleur hanger extension or other method to accommodate a larger cassette sprocket, then total capacity does need to be taken into account.

Comment: +1 for considering the RD capacity.  Although if he's switching to a MTB RD I don't think this will be an issue (MTB doubles have a 14t difference, so very similar).

Comment: @Argenti Apparatus, I made up my mind. From my previous question about XTR shifter with Dura-Ace RD and FD. Now I conclude I should go with XTR Shifter and RD. That's why I ask this question so I could get an idea to what crankset teeth combination should I get. I have checked Shimano's website and their top tier XTR RD-M9000-SGS has a minimum sprocket teeth count of 42T. Can you advise what crankset is good/compatible with that cassette?

Comment: @WashichawbachaW specific product recomendations are off topic here. if you are trying to fit a road crank you need to consider the bottom bracket compatibility and chain line, chain stay clearance and spread of gear ratios, i.e it's not simple.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus yeah I get that. I just want to be specific on the model so there will be no incompatibilities for any recommendations you guys will suggest. BB and chainstay clearance are good though.

Answer (score 2):

With the exception that you might not be able to find a long enough chain, there is no relationship between compatibility and tooth count between a cassette and a crankset.

If you want to stick with shimano, the largest available for 11 speed is 11-46, however there are alternatives (like sunrace) that can do up to an 11-50 cassette

Comment: +1 for considering chain length, although you could always splice two chains together.